# How to play videos in one frame?

Tags: javascript, php, html, video, html5-video

I want to add 4 videos to my web page, but I want A.mp4 video Play first until the end, and then video B.mp4 and then C.mp4 video, and D.mp4, and back to first video when all finished(looping). And I want that all video in one frame, like youtube playlist.

This is the script for video

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var videos = $('video').each(function(index){
        $(this).bind('ended', function(){
            var video = videos[index + 1];
            video && video.play();
        });
    });
    if(videos.get(0).play){
        videos.get(0).play();
    }
});
</script>
```

and this the php where the video is placed:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12" style="background-color:white;">
        <br>

<video controls preload="auto" src="http://www.freecybers.com/tv/asset/playlist_HTML5/lake.mp4">Video format not supported.</video>
<video controls preload="auto" src="http://www.freecybers.com/tv/asset/playlist_HTML5/mountain.mp4">Video format not supported.</video>
<video controls preload="auto" src="http://www.freecybers.com/tv/asset/playlist_HTML5/glacier.mp4">Video format not supported.</video>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Continuous Play of video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665920/continuous-play-of-video)

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just make one long video out of your shorter videos?

Comment: @aldel there are such use cases: see for example scores table at nhl.com - http://www.nhl.com/ice/scores.htm?navid=nav-scr-main - it's really useful and comfortable to have multiple videos consecutively running